# Parrallelize filter and collect

Tags: java, java-stream

How do we parallelize filter and add into a single collect operation - something like

```
List<Employee> result= emps.parallelStream().collect(new ArrayList<Employee>(),
                  a.add(emps.filter(e -> e.getSalary() > 30))//conceptually,
                  (a,b) -> a.addAll(b));
```

Is this possible?

Comment: After use `parallel`, it's already parallelize

Comment: You *can* do it manually as `emps.parallelStream().collect(() -> new ArrayList<>(), (a,e) -> { if(e.getSalary() > 30) a.add(e); }, (a,b) -> a.addAll(b))`, but there is no reason to do so, as using the builtin functionality [`.filter(e -> e.getSalary() > 30) .collect(Collectors.toList())`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261366/2711488) is much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `parallelStream()` is called `filter` and `collect` called on this stream will be executed in parallel.

```
List<Employee> result= emps.parallelStream()
   .filter(e -> e.getSalary() > 30)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```